# What is physical interpretation of the band structure diagrams $E=f(k)$?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory, dispersion

What is the actual meaning of the lines given in the band structure diagram? For example, the $E=f(k)$ relation for a simple 1-dimensional periodic lattice is $E(k) = -2\cos(k)$.

[image]

1. What is the physical meaning of this graph? It is showing the energy of a particle at a specific k-point. Does it mean that when our particle is moving in the k-vector direction, it has to change its energy?
2. In this case, there is only one band (only one line). In some other examples, I have seen there are many more bands. What does more than one band mean?

Comment: Note that $k$ is not automatically dimensionless, so you can't really use it alone inside a cosine function (or any function representable as a power series, for that matter). If $k$ is meant to be dimensionless in this case, what characteristic length are you implicitly multiplying it by?

Comment: $k$ is related to the wavelength of the particle. It does not change when the particle is moving.

Comment: @probably_someone usually it's multiplied by the lattice spacing $a$ for a real material but lots of toy models will set that to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Electrons in a lattice are subject to a periodic potential $V(\vec{r})=V(\vec{r}+\vec{R})$ which has the periodicity of the lattice. The relation $E(\vec{k})$ comes from solving Schrödinger's equation in this periodic potential. It can be shown ([Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem)) that the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are of the form
$$\psi_{\vec{k}}(\vec{r})=e^{\displaystyle i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}u_{\vec{k}}(\vec{r})\ .$$
Notice several things:

1. The possible energies of an electron in this lattice will depend on $\vec{k}$, since the energy eigenstates depend on this parameter.
   $$\hat{H}\psi_{\vec{k}}=E\psi_{\vec{k}}\quad\implies\quad E=E(\vec{k})$$
2. The energies will also depend on a quantum number $n$, as we would expect for bound states. Therefore $E=E_n(\vec{k})$. The number $n$ is what we call the band, each $n$ labels a different one, and the relation in your figure is just the plot of $E(\vec{k})$ for a given band.
3. You can think of $\vec{k}$ as a tag for the electron, just as $n$. It is related to the expected value of the momentum $\vec{p}$ of the electron, but it's not exactly that. The quantity that is conserved when the electron interacts with other particles (e.g. photons, phonons, etc) is what is called the quasimomentum $\hbar\vec{k}$. A nice discussion on the meaning of $\vec{k}$ can be found in [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111286/149907).

Answer (score 1):

It is analogous to a gas of particles, where each particle has a momentum $\mathbf p_k$ and an energy $E_k = \frac{p_k^2}{2m}$.

The first big difference is that for the bands the energy is quantized, so only discrete value of momentum and energy are allowed.

The second difference is that the same value of $k$ means different values of energy and crystal momentum, and that is the meaning of several bands.